# How do I replace spaces into hyphens in an URL

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some data that is inputted into to a database with spaces. e.g. first and last names. I then need to call that data from the database and display it as a link so i have a friendly URL. I am not sure if I should do this with mod-rewrite or php. What is the best solution?

A  solution like below doesn't seem to work

```
str_replace('- ','-',$url);

echo "<p><span class=\"barting\">"."<a href=$url=\"jobs/".$row['jobid']."/".$row['title']."\">".$row['title']."</a></span>";

echo $url
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 3):

You wrote

`str_replace('- ','-',$url);`

But this code don't replace white spaces, to replace white spaces you should use:

`$url = str_replace(' ','-',$url);`

or you can use [urlencode](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

`urlencode($url)`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use urlencode(), which will turn the spaces into %20.  But if you want to do what you're doing, you have to remember that str_replace RETURNS the replaced string, it does not modify the var you pass in.

So you need 
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url);

Answer (score 0):

A URL rewrite is not necessary. It sounds like your goal is to simply build a URL that looks something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/firstname-lastname/jobs/1234567/sometitle
```

To replace only spaces with hyphens in $url, try

```
str_replace(" ", "-", $url);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i want but how do i implement it into my code? How do I get it to affect my code.